# Embed a PDF on a ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, pdf

Im trying to embed a PDF on to my page, but the PDF just does not load. I have checked the file path which is correct.

When the page first loads, I get a blank grey embed field, however when I click on the embed, I get this (which stays like this):

[image: Loading remains like this]

```
<script>
    var selected_doc_ref = "";
    function getPDF() {

        //selected_doc_ref = "395";

        var DV_pdf_path = "../../../Document_Viewer/Risk_Assessment/RISK ASSESSMENT 1024.pdf";

        var pdf = document.getElementById("pdf");
        var clone = pdf.cloneNode(true);
        clone.setAttribute('src', DV_pdf_path);
        pdf.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, pdf)
    }
</script>


<body onload="getPDF()">

<embed id="pdf" style="border-radius: 10px;position: relative;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:620px;"/>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have pdf reader plugin for your browser installed? Adobe's acrobat readers installs it per default

Comment: Yes, PDF reader is installed. I am converting this application from a static HTML to a ASP.NET application. It works from the static HTML. Screenshot added above to show what I get from the .NET

Comment: Ah, I think you should set the "src" attribute from the <embed> tag at the beginning and not after page load. I suppose the browser does not refresh the already rendered pdf window when you update it through javascript. Maybe you can force a refresh somehow. Another possibility would be to add the whole embed tag dynamically, instead of just setting its src tag. That would cause it to rerender it completly

Comment: I see what you mean, it works when the SRC is static. Any ideas how I would add the whole tag dynamically? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the browser does not refresh the embed tag when you add the `src` attribute to the `<embed>` tag after page load you have 2 options:

- Set the src attribute on the `<embed>` tag directly so it is available from the beginning on. You could set the `src` through code behind or as a static value.
- In your javascript, add the whole `<embed>` tag inside the `getPDF()` function instead of just the attribute `src`:

  ```
  var e = document.createElement('embed');
  e.attributes['src'] = src;
  e.attributes['style'] = "border-radius: 10px;position: relative;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:620px;";
  document.getElementById("pdfContainer").appendChild(e);
  ```

**Assuming that you have a element with id "pdfContainer" where you want to place the `<embed>` tag inside.**